# FFmpeg append Audio duration to File Name

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm working on processing some audio files, I'm to get the audio duration and append the duration to the file name i.e `audio-lecture-02.30.05.mp3`.I have able to get the audio duration using FFmpeg using `ffmpeg -i lecture.mp3 2>&1 | grep Duration` and the output is `Duration: 01:27:25.70, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 64 kb/s` is there a way to extract this duration and append the file name? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The output from `ffmpeg` is not meant to be machine parsed. Use `ffprobe` instead.

## Append duration in seconds

```
#!/bin/bash
input="input.mp3"
duration=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of csv=p=0 "$input")
mv "$input" "${input%.*}-$duration.${input##*.}"
```

Results in `input-5025.670000.mp3`.

## Append duration in HH.MM.SS.ms

```
#!/bin/bash
input="input.mp3"
duration=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -sexagesimal -of csv=p=0 "$input")
mv "$input" "${input%.*}-${duration//:/.}.${input##*.}"
```

Results in `input-1.23.45.670000.mp3`.